# Local ESM delivery like JSDelivr

Tags: node.js, apache, npm, es6-modules

I want to setup my local apache delivery the way like jsdelivr.com?
Why? Cause once in a while jsdelivr is down and my site can't load. And I'd want to avoid suck situations.

For instance, I use confetti module and in my local confetty-load.js there is import:

```
import { confetti } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tsparticles-confetti/+esm";
```

The task is to move all these to my local apache server.
I've already installed the needs inside my local directory of apache by npm install:

```
npm install tsparticles-confetti
```

So, how to setup my apache to work like jsdelvr using import like:

```
import { confetti } from "/local/directory/tsparticles-confetti/esm/index.js";
```

If I've changing

```
import { confetti } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tsparticles-confetti/+esm";
```

to ...

```
import { confetti } from "../lib/node_modules/tsparticles-confetti/esm/index.js";
```

it is not worked with
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tsparticles-engine". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Looks like apache does not know how to load dependencies